# Error Changing Sheet Name (Based On Value Of Cell) When Copying Sheet- Excel- VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The following code successfully changes the sheet name based on the value in cell "E26" i.e. if the value in "E26" is 'Test', sheet name will be named 'Test'.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Target = Range("E26")
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
Application.ActiveSheet.Name = VBA.Left(Target, 31)
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Problem is, if I copy the sheet but want to keep the value in cell "E26" the same, the copied sheet name becomes "Test (1)" but I get a `Run time error '1004': That name is already taken. Try a different one.` obviously.

Question: How can I automatically add a number after each subsequent copy of the sheet i.e. Test (1), Test (2), etc. to avoid getting the error while still keeping the value in cell "E26" the same i.e. Test?

Comment: Do you have other sheets in the file not called Test? You are not understanding how events work - `Target` is the cell selected. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the idea, but try to count the current sheets in your book and concat to the name you want

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`
    Set Target = Range("E26")
    Dim nSheets As Double
    nSheets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
    '+1 is optional in order you have a secuence
    Application.ActiveSheet.Name = Target & "(" & nSheets + 1 & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: This does work preventing the error by adding (1), (2), (3), etc. to end of every subsequent copy of the sheet regardless of the sheet name.  However, I was only looking to do that for duplicate sheet names.  For example, if I were to copy the sheet named 'Test' with 'Test' in cell E26, sheet would be named 'Test (2)'.  Perfect.  However, if I were to change cell E26 to 'Trial' in that copied sheet 'Test (2)', the sheet name would become 'Trial (2)' versus just 'Trial' since there are no previous sheets with that name. Don't know how to modify your code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a bit more complex solution that hopefully also addesses all sort of end cases.

First, let's create a helper function that can answer the question "Is there a sheet with the name x?".

```
Function sheetExists(name) As Boolean

    sheetExists = False
    
    For i = 1 To Application.Worksheets.Count
        shtName = Application.Worksheets(i).name
        If shtName = name Then
          sheetExists = True
          Exit Function
        End If
      Next
      
End Function
```

Now that we have that option, let's build the actual code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    MaxTabs = 10 ' Adjust this number as needed.

    BaseName = Range("E26").Value
    If (BaseName = "") Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    name = BaseName
    i = 0
    
    For i = 1 To MaxTabs
        If (Not sheetExists(name)) Then
            Application.ActiveSheet.name = name
            Exit Sub
        End If
            
        name = BaseName + " (" + Trim(Str(i)) + ")"
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Worksheet Change

- You could rather use the `Worksheet_Change event` and suppress the error(s) by using `On Error`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Intersect(Range("E26"), Target)
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        On Error GoTo clearError
        Me.Name = Left(rg.Value, 31)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    Exit Sub
clearError:
    'Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub
```